Postgres 'invalid input syntax for type uuid' error interrupts Laravel 11.x validation
I'm encountering an issue in my Laravel application where the validation process stops working due to a "invalid input syntax for type uuid" error from Postgres. This occurs when I try to validate a UUID field using Laravel's validation rules, and the field fails validation due to an invalid UUID format.
Here's the relevant part of my validation rule:
'id' => ['required', new UUIDValidationRule, 'exists:table,id']
The problem seems to be that Laravel's validation system attempts to check database existence (exists:table,id) before validating the UUID format, leading to the Postgres error.

By adding the bail rule after the UUIDValidationRule, Laravel will stop the validation process if the UUID format validation fails. This prevents the "invalid input syntax for type uuid" error from being triggered during the database existence check.
Additionally, you can use the bail rule in other validation scenarios where you want to prioritize certain rules and halt validation on the first failure.
I hope this helps! Let me know if you have any further questions or issues.
